# local storage data not being bound to data

Tags: vue.js

i have a component, which calls a footer component. inside the footer component, i have a modal that shows on click. i want the title of that modal to be a data variable, and i want to set that data variable with data from local storage. for some reason, its not appearing.

I know that the data is in local storage. Any idea's?

```
export default {
  name: "FooterComponent",
  data: () => {
    return {
      privacy_modal: false,
      privacy_title: '',
      privacy_content: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    beforeMount() {
      this.privacy_title = localStorage.getItem("privacy_title");
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Are you local Storage variable already set ?

Comment: where did you set the localStrorage? we are not seeing that part. for example if you setting that item after mount, then you can't get it, because calling it `beforeMount`

Comment: Can you check your localStorage object from within your browser's developer tools and how does the plain object look like? Can you show us?

Comment: As a sanity check, maybe set `this.privacy_title = localStorage.getItem("privacy_title") || "not found"` - this will help narrow down where the issue is.

Also @vadivela OP said he knows that the data is in localStorage already.

Comment: I set the variable long before this component is rendered, during log in. I also added || 'not found' and nothing shows up.

Comment: Check with Vue Devtools. May be you are displaying different component.

Answer (score 0):

`beforeMount` is a lifecycle hook, not a method. It must be defined directly within options, not inside `methods`:

```
export default {
  name: "FooterComponent",
  data() {
    return {
      privacy_modal: false,
      privacy_title: '',
      privacy_content: ''
    };
  },

  beforeMount() {
    this.privacy_title = localStorage.getItem("privacy_title"); // || "some default value"
  },

  methods: {
    // custom methods
  }
};
```

Also, don't forget to update local storage, as demanded by your app logic.